# Update contents of MTLBuffer in Metal

Tags: ios, metal

I need help to replace the contents of a **MTLBuffer** without creating a new one. Content in both cases are Float Arrays.

```
let vector:[Float] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   
let byteLength = arr1.count*MemoryLayout<Float>.size
let buffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: &vector, length: byteLength, options: MTLResourceOptions())

let vector2:[Float] = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
```

I understand **buffer.contents()** gives us a **UnsafeMutableRawPointer**. I would like to create a new UnsafeMutableRawPointer from **vector2** and replace the contents of buffer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with `memcpy`, but the slightly Swiftier way is:

```
buffer.contents().copyMemory(from: vector2, byteCount: vector2.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)
```

In general, prefer `stride` over `size` when calculating the length of an array in bytes. If the type is not primitive and has any padding, `size` will not account for this, and you'll copy fewer bytes than you intended.

Comment: With Xcode 14 and Swift 5.7 it is now called `copyMemory(…)`