# Value of type 'MTLBuffer' has no member 'didModifyRange'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal

I am confused as I have created a MTLBuffer in Swift 4 yet am unable to use the method didModifyRange.

Interestingly enough I can still find this in the Apple documentation and have not heard of this being changed.

Why is the error `Value of type 'MTLBuffer' has no member 'didModifyRange'` happening?

The following code would generate this error in the latest version of XCode

```
let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
var buffer = device?.makeBuffer(length: 3, options: [])
let range = Range<Int>(NSRange())
buffer.didModifyRange(range)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/2928174-didmodifyrange), signature of the method looks like this:

```
func didModifyRange(_ range: Range<Int>)
```

You pass `NSRange` which is obviously different from Swift `Range<Int>`. So to get it work, simply pass proper range object.

P.S. `Range<Int>` is defined with `min...max` scheme (e.g. `0...100`).

**EDIT:**

Some `Metal` framework signatures are only available on macOS 11.1, including `didModifyRange:`, so if you try to call it on iOS, even having `import Metal` in the header, will give you that error.

So the following code will compile under macOS 11.1

```
import Metal
//  ...

    guard
        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
        let buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: 3, options: [])
        else {
            return
    }

    buffer.didModifyRange(Range<Int>(1...10))
```

...and will not, under iOS.

Comment: Unfortunately I still cant get it to work even with the correct type for the range. I have updated the code to show this. It still says the same thing.

Comment: Well, this is interesting indeed. Everything seems alright and docs say the method is there...

Comment: To cut it short, this method is only available in macOS 11.1+,  iOS not supported.

Comment: OH! I see that now.... so then the only way to update a buffer now is to copyBytes? That doesnt seem right but all the documentation points to this? Is there no way to update a buffer without copying on a device with unified cpu and gpu memory?

Comment: It appears so... But those are good questions. I'm not that proficient with `Metal` so far, maybe community can tell.
[On copyBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561558/update-contents-of-mtlbuffer-in-metal).

Comment: `didModifyRange()` is not needed on iOS since the CPU and GPU share the same memory. On macOS it's needed because the GPU may have its own RAM, and `didModifyRange()` tells Metal to copy the bytes from this range to the GPU's memory.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans so to actually change the data on iOS, do we change the Swift buffer (which was originally used by `device.makeBuffer` to create the `MTLBuffer`)? Or do we need to directly change the  `MTLBuffer` somehow, e.g. using `.contents()` raw mutable pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have initialised your `MTLBuffer buffer` you can obtain a typed pointer to it using

```
let x = buffer.contents().bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: 1000)
```

This returns the same address as `buffer.contents()` but it's stride is aligned to the size of `Float`, where you have registered there being `capacity` floats in total. Change these parameters as required.

Now you can directly update/access the data via

```
x[0] = 3.14

x[5] = 1.59

etc.
```

See Apples's [bindMemory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2428061-bindmemory) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS there is no `didModifyRange()`. It's only available on macOS.

Instead I ended up doing like this:

```
var myVertices: [MyVertex]

...
myVertices[0].color = float4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1)
...

mltBuffer.contents().copyMemory(
    from: myVertices, 
    byteCount: myVertices.count * MemoryLayout<MyVertex>.stride
)
```

Comment: Is this necessary on iOS? I read in the comments of another answer that iOS devices share memory between CPU and GPU so a copy may not be necessary at all. Trying to figure this out myself. Your answer helped.

Comment: @Pixel I don't know whats right and wrong, since I don't work at Apple, and don't know how the CPU and GPU talks with each other. This was what I found out myself in order to get my opensource app working. My code is online here: https://github.com/triangledraw/TriangleDraw-iOS/blob/42832665631eaa12b2fee2a34b89650195723b56/Source/TriangleDrawMain/Canvas/HCRenderer.swift#L301

Comment: turns out the buffer can be manipulated directly without the need to copy a separate buffer over (details in my answer below)

Comment: @Pixel aha that's neat. I have to integrate your code into my project.